# Change value of dataframe which based on in r

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a matrix and a vector just like

```
data = matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=3)
index = c(1,2,1)
```

the `nrow(data)=length(index)`
I want get the `ith` row and the `index[i]`of data to be 1,just like

```
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
```

TO

```
1,0,0
0,1,0
1,0,0
```

Comment: `data[cbind(seq_along(index), index)] <- 1` [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811018/replacing-matrix-elements-indexed-by-another-matrix)

Comment: That's work,Thanks a lot !